# Efficient way to use max_by with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I've been trying to figure out how to use `max_by` and `max` methods, with multiple conditions. While I thought I did, after extensive testing it turned out not to be the case.

For example, I have a hash whose values are hashes:

```
chapters = { "686050": {
        "volume": '1',
        "chapter": '1',
        "title": 'Chapter Title',
        "lang_code": 'gb',
        "timestamp": 1_565_434_815
      },
      "686049": {
        "volume": '2',
        "chapter": '1',
        "title": 'Chapter Title',
        "lang_code": 'gb',
        "timestamp": 1_565_300_815
      },
      "686048": {
        "volume": '2',
        "chapter": '2',
        "title": 'Chapter Title',
        "lang_code": 'gb',
        "timestamp": 1_565_300_815
      }
    }
```

I want to find one hash, that has the maximum volume AND chapter. So in this case, I am expecting to get the one with volume 2 and chapter 2.

My first implementation was using `max`:

```rb
chapters.max do |a, b|
  a[1][:volume].to_d <=> b[1][:volume].to_d &&
    a[1][:chapter].to_d <=> b[1][:chapter].to_d
end
```

When looking at this, my thinking was that it would first compare by volume and then by chapter. This code have worked... until I changed the hash to be:

```rb
  "686050": {
    "volume": '1',
    "chapter": '1',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_434_815
  },
  "686049": {
    "volume": '2',
    "chapter": '1',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_300_815
  }
```

Which suddenly started to return the one with volume 1 and chapter 2! I am still unsure why this was happening...

So I decided to try `max_by`, using this `chapters.max_by { |_, v| v[:volume].to_d && v[:chapter].to_d }`, with the same assumption. Which also ended up failing for when there is a single chapter per volume.

My solution ended up being:

```rb
chapters
  .group_by { |_, v| v[:volume].to_d }.max.last.to_h
  .max_by { |_, v| v[:chapter].to_d }
```

Which works for obvious reasons, but feels quite inefficient. There must be a way to use a single `max` or `max_by`. Would love to hear some ideas on this

Comment: I trust you don't object to my edit. I mainly added the variable `h` to hold your hash so that readers could refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: Not at all @CarySwoveland, although I'd edit it to be chapters, as that's what I use and is what referenced in my code blocks

Comment: I believe there is a problem with your code. Please see my comment on @calvin's answer. If you set `chapters = book2` after modifying `book2` as I suggested, your code returns `[:"686049", {:volume=>"2", :chapter=>"1", :title=>"Chapter Title", :lang_code=>"gb", :timestamp=>1565300815}]`, which I do not think meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following.

```
def max_val(h,key)
  h.map { |_,g| g[key] }.max
end

max_volume = max_val(h, :volume)    #=> "2"
max_chapter = max_val(h, :chapter)  #=> "2"

chapters.find { |_,g| g[:volume] == max_volume && g[:chapter] == max_chapter } 
  #=> [:"686048", {:volume=>"2", :chapter=>"2", :title=>"Chapter Title",
  #                :lang_code=>"gb", :timestamp=>1565300815}]
```

`nil` is returned if no value contains the maximum values of both keys. Replace `find` with `select` if all key-value pairs having the desired property are to be returned (i.e., if there are ties). That array would be empty if no value contains the maximum values of both keys.

This requires three passes through the hash. It could be done in a single pass but it's messy and I expect it would be more time-consuming, largely because `Enumerable#map` and `Array#max` are both implemented in C.

The desired result could be obtained in a single pass as follows.

```
max_volume  = 0.chr
max_chapter = 0.chr
candidate = [nil, {}]
chapters.each do |k,g|
  old_max_volume = max_volume
  max_volume = [max_volume, g[:volume]].max
  old_max_chapter = max_chapter 
  max_chapter = [max_chapter, g[:chapter]].max
  if max_volume > old_max_volume || max_chapter > old_max_chapter
    candidate = (max_volume == g[:volume] && max_chapter == g[:chapter]) ? 
     [k,g] : [nil, {}]
  end
end
candidate
  #=> [:"686048", {:volume=>"2", :chapter=>"2", :title=>"Chapter Title",
  #    :lang_code=>"gb", :timestamp=>1565300815}]
```

Now set:

```
chapters[:"686048"][:volume] = '1'
```

The first method above now returns `nil`, the second (one-pass), returns `[nil, {}]`

Comment: Yup, there are tied books as well. For that reason, there is a step before that, which sorts books by timestamp, so that max_by picks the first one, which is the latest uploaded.

Yup, that one pass looks like a mess. Readability is more important than performance for me, so your first suggestion is good. I'll probably stick with mine though, as its a bit more neat, even if there are few more steps in there

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

```rb
# example 1
a = %w[albatross dog horse]
a.max_by(2) {|x| x.length } #=> ["albatross", "horse"]

# example 2 - Arrays are compared in an “element-wise” manner
arrays = [['1', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['2', '2']]
arrays.max_by(2) { |arr| arr } #=> ["2","2"], ["2", "1"]
```

So

```rb
chapters.max_by { |_, elem| [elem[:volume], elem[:chapter]] }
```

Let's test

```rb
book1 = { 
  "686050": {
    "volume": '1',
    "chapter": '1',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_434_815
  },
  "686049": {
    "volume": '2',
    "chapter": '1',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_300_815
  },
  "686048": {
    "volume": '2',
    "chapter": '2',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_300_815
  }
}

book2 = {
  "686050": {
    "volume": '1',
    "chapter": '1',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_434_815
  },
  "686049": {
    "volume": '2',
    "chapter": '1',
    "title": 'Chapter Title',
    "lang_code": 'gb',
    "timestamp": 1_565_300_815
  }  
}

pp book1.max_by(2) { |_, elem| [elem[:volume], elem[:chapter]] }
pp book2.max_by { |_, elem| [elem[:volume], elem[:chapter]] }
```

outputs

```
# 1st test
[[:"686048",
  {:volume=>"2",
   :chapter=>"2",
   :title=>"Chapter Title",
   :lang_code=>"gb",
   :timestamp=>1565300815}],
 [:"686049",
  {:volume=>"2",
   :chapter=>"1",
   :title=>"Chapter Title",
   :lang_code=>"gb",
   :timestamp=>1565300815}]]

# 2nd test
[:"686049",
 {:volume=>"2",
  :chapter=>"1",
  :title=>"Chapter Title",
  :lang_code=>"gb",
  :timestamp=>1565300815}]
```

Comment: Suppose your `book2` were altered as follows: `book2[:"686050"][:chapter] = '2'`. Then `book2.max_by { |_, elem| [elem[:volume], elem[:chapter]] }
 => [:"686049", {:volume=>"2",...}]`, but that is incorrect because no value of `h` contains *both* the maximum value of  `:volume` *and* the maximum value of `:chapter`.